# TFS Branching, Merging, and Inner-Repository Dependencies

Tags: tfs

My team shares a TFS repository with several other teams and therefore do not have much flexibility. We have a couple of apps that we develop that depend on other parts of the repository that we don't have write access to--let's call these frameworks.

When changes are made to the frameworks, we need those changes. However, we don't want the frameworks team to have to check-in/merge to multiple branches, so instead, we end up keeping the repository intact, but whenever we want to build, we manually copy the newest framework into a new folder. These makes us lose all the features of source control.

Is it possible to create the structure we need for each of our apps into individual branches, then when folks in the frameworks check-in changes, they are automatically applied to all of our branches? Do we need hard links? Branches within branches with automatic merging?

Replies are greatly appreciated.

Comment: are the "frameworks" code artifacts or DLL's you could reference from your project?

Comment: They are full directories and projects. That why I thought that perhaps a hard link might be the answer, but I don't know how hard links would work in a TFS repository.

Comment: so it is more than just "binaries" needed from the "frameworks" ?